# R: Parsing HTML Table Results in Factors Instead of Characters

Tags: r

I have a function that parses the rows of an HTML:

```
xmlToCsv <- function(xml) {
    a <- gsub('\n\n','\t', xmlValue(xml))
    b <- gsub('\t\t','\t \t', a)
    d <- gsub('\t\t','\t', b)
    e <- gsub('^ |\t$','', d)
    f <- gsub('\t ','\t', e)
    cc <- c("numeric", "numeric", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character", "character")
    cn <- c("EngNumber", "JpNumber", "Icon", "EngSet", "JpSet", "EngCardCount", "JpCardCount", "EngDate", "JpDate")
    g <- read.table(text=f, sep="\t", header=FALSE)
    colnames(g) <- cn
    keeps <- c("EngNumber", "EngSet", "EngCardCount")
    return(g[keeps])
}
```

I use this function like this:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

theurl <- "http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_Trading_Card_Game_expansions"
webpage <- getURL(theurl)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
tr <- getNodeSet(pagetree, "//*/tr")
sets <- tr[4:length(tr)-1]
dsets <- sapply(sets, xmlToCsv)
```

The sets variable holds each row of the HTML table that I am interested in. For example, sets[1] looks like:

```
sets[1]
[[1]]
<tr><th> 1
</th>
<td> 1
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td> <a href="/wiki/Base_Set_(TCG)" title="Base Set (TCG)">Base Set</a>
</td>
<td> Expansion Pack
</td>
<td> 102
</td>
<td> 102
</td>
<td> January 9, 1999
</td>
<td> October 20, 1996
</td></tr>
```

The contents of dsets is more complex than I know what to do with. I'd like a data frame that looks like:

```
  EngNumber Icon             EngSet EngCardCount
1        58   NA Legendary Treasures         138
2        61   NA Furious Fists               113
```

Am I close? Do I have the right approach? I'm very new to R and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I did not. However, after looking at xmlToDataFrame, it's unclear how I would pass sets[1] (one row of the HTML table) into the xmlToDataFrame.

Comment: Actually I think `readHTMLTable` would be better for this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue comes from using `sapply` instead of `lapply`. `sapply` tries to simplify your result, while you want to `rbind` each value of `xmlToCsv`. You may obtain a `data.frame` using `lapply` and `do.call`:

```
     dsets <- lapply(sets, xmlToCsv)
     do.call(rbind,dsets)
```